# Inconsistent behavior of IE10 with nth-child and nth-of-type

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-10, html-table, css-selectors

With a table such as this one:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr><td>1</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>4</td></tr>
        <tr><td>5</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I try to get, say line 3 out of all lines (including the one in the THEAD), like this :

```
table.querySelector("tr:nth-of-type(3)");
```

I get line 4. Besides, using 5 as the value of *:nth-of-type* return null. Using 4 returns the last (fifth) line. It happens that the first line of TBODY is missing (value 1 returns the line in THEAD).

Is this an IE bug or am I doing something wrong? My environment is WinJS by the way, which uses IE 10 as its JavaScript engine.

I double checked that *:nth-of-type* is 1 based, not 0 based. I have the exact same result with *:nth-child*.

Comment: [This example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ygJBx) works fine in IE 10 and returns the correct row. Do you experience the same in your IE and in your environment with this code?

Comment: This does not seem to be an issue with the IE10 implementation, unless Firefox is also bugged - see [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qantas94Heavy/Gmrjc/3), which returns `<td>4</td>` in both Firefox and IE10.

Comment: Thx for the JSFiddle. On IE10 (outside my environment) it does it plain wrong. *:nth-child(1)* returns 1. *:nth-child(2)* returns 3. So it's not linked to the tbody as one might think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.

*:nth-child* and *:nth-of-type* return the nth element of its parent.

But the TRs have different parents (THEAD and TBODY), even if they're part of the same table. This is what messes up the result.

If you do :

```
table.querySelectorAll("tr:nth-of-type(1)");
```

The array contains two elements. The first TR of respectively the THEAD and the TBODY.

Calling nth-of-type(2) returns TR number 3 because... it's indeed the only TR in the table that is the second child of its parent, TBODY.

What I need is a selector that takes element n°X among all elements found, but that doesn't exist (as far as I know).